# Highcharts line chart in Ext JS Panel

Tags: highcharts, extjs3

I am working on a simple chart with Highcharts on ExtJS 3.* version. I am using this simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-linewidth-specific/). I don't want to render this chart to a `div` element. I want to put this in a `Ext.Panel` but when I tried it gives error. How can I do without chart's `renderTo`property.

Comment: Have you seen our wrappers to java, http://www.highcharts.com/download ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sebastian Bochan stated [highcharts.com/download](http://www.highcharts.com/download) solved my problem.